# Горсть, пригоршня и жменя

Tags: лексика

"Горсть" — слово, равное по значению слову "пригоршня"? Горсть может подразумевать как вместе сложенные ладони, так и одну с сомкнутыми пальцами ладонь (то бишь жменю)? Пригоршня — то же самое?

Answer (score 3):

Мне 66 лет.
Когда я была ребёнком, моя Старая бабушка (так я называла свою прабабушку) научила меня рецепту каши и показала:

> ЩЕПОТЬ соли,
> ЖМЕНЯ сахару,
> ГОРСТЬ крупы,
> да ПРИГОРШНЯ воды.

ЩЕПОТЬ это то, что набирается тремя первыми пальцами одной руки.
ЖМЕНЯ это то, что набирается пятью пальцами одной руки и зажимается в кулаке.
ГОРСТЬ это то, что насыпается в одну ладонь, согнутую ковшиком. По объёму взятого ЖМЕНЯ и ГОРСТЬ разные.
ПРИГОРШНЯ это то, что набирается или насыпается/наливается в обе ладони, согнутые ковшиком и прижатые друг к другу рёбрами ладоней.

Comment: Как я умудрился не узнать этого раньше?

Answer (score 1):

**Горсть** - вместилище из *одной* ладони, **пригоршня** - из обеих. **Жменя** - *диалектный* (донской) вариант "горсти". Некоторые словари приводят это слово, но с пометкой "местн."

Answer (score 0):

> "Горсть" — слово, равное по значению слову "пригоршня"?

Вообще, нет, но есть общее значение.

> Горсть может подразумевать как вместе сложенные ладони, так и одну согнутую ладонь (то бишь жменю)?

Нет, не может. Только одну согнутую ладонь.

> Пригоршня может подразумевать как вместе сложенные ладони, так и одну согнутую ладонь (то бишь жменю)?

А вот *пригоршня* может подразумевать и одну согнутую ладонь (тогда она совпадает по значению с "горстью"), и обе сложенные вместе ладони.